# Why do we say that the quran of ibn mas'ud is LOST? while we have some (?) variant

Tags: quran, tafseer, history, qiraat, mushaf

Salam
I know we have  Kitab al-Masahif of Ibn Abi Dawood relating some variant of the mushaf of ibn mas'ud.
I also heared that we have some variant in tafsir

Can we make the whole mushaf of ibn mas'ud today or they is some missing parts and that s why everyone said it s lost .
or maybe we have conflicting hadeeth about the same verse.

I dont understand .

Thanks you

Comment: These are already three questions, you should edit your post and ask each of them separately (see in [our meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions)). Secondly Ibn abi Dawood is not a good source if only because of his father's statements about his abilities of transmission(he regarded him not trustworthy and a fabricator). Thirdly what is your concept of "The qur'an of ibn  Mas'ud" elaborate!

Comment: Sorry I edited my question to one and unique question , why do we say that the MUSHAF of ibn mas'ud is lost while he have some part in different text